# Developing android applications on an arm processor

Tags: android, arm

I'm wanting to develop android applications on Ubuntu which is on an ARM processor.
I've looked for an android sdk that will run on an arm processor but all I can find is the x86 version on the android site.

Does anyone know where I can get an ARM version?

Comment: One option, if you can't find it, would be to download the source tree and build the sdk tools from source with an ARM compiler although that's a toooon of effort.

Comment: I've had the horrible thought that doing it myself might be the answer, hopefully not.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this install of Ubuntu running on your Android device itself... because, if so, I am trying to accomplish the exact same thing.

Comment: Ubuntu is running on the android. I couldn't get it to work in the end...or more accurately I didn't have the time to spend trying to get it too work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no port of the Android SDK to the ARM processor that I am aware of. I'm not even sure that there's a port of the Java JDK to the ARM processor, and that is a prerequisite for the Android SDK.

Comment: I'm using OpenJDK for Java. This took quite a bit of finding.

Answer (score 1):

[Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&feature=md) on the play store contains the Android SDK, and the tools you need to develop Android applications pre-compiled for ARM.

It also includes a 4 page terminal emulator and VIM for coding/building directly on the device.

If you wanted to compile under Ubuntu (on device) you could probably install it and copy out the ARM compiled binaries to roll your own development environment.

I believe [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&feature=md) is similar, but provides a GUI code editor instead of VIM. But I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

My environment is Ubuntu Precise chrooted on a Xoom tablet. Ubuntu was installed using Linux Deploy from Google Play.

Both Qt Creator and Eclipse for armhf include SDK and JDK. However, in Eclipse they have to be installed via 'Install Software' accessed through 'Help', 'Options'. I'm still involved in steps necessary to configure both programs and can't say positively yet that the Qt Creator SDK has been installed by default.

I've turned my attention to finding a toolchain which will most likely have to be installed from source. Thus far it looks like the [GNU version](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/toolchain-install/) will be my first choice.

My objective is to develop an Android version of [OpenCPN](http://opencpn.org/ocpn/), an open source navigation and charting program.